# Оператор "или" в проверке якоря

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно проверять несколько якорей и выполнять действия, как это сделать ?

Мой код не работает почему-то:

```js
if (window.location.hash == '#dynamic') && (window.location.hash == '#testing') {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#tabs').offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: _Мой код не работает почему-то_ - потому что `&&` - это логическое "И", а логическое "ИЛИ" - это `||`

Comment: Точно, спасибо!)

Answer (score 0):

Условие не правильное

```
if ((window.location.hash == '#dynamic') || (window.location.hash == '#testing')) {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#tabs').offset().top
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: и чем твое условие отличается от условия в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy, ой, хотел `||` поставить

Answer (score 0):

Сделал минималистический пример на jQuery. В ссылку через # записывается id блока, к которому нужно перейти, однако в URL хеши не добавляются. Работает для любой ссылки на странице, в которой указан id блока для перехода.

```js
// Page a Link Smooth Scrolling
$("[href^='#']").click(function() {
var idtop = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
$('html,body').animate(
    // Time animation
    {scrollTop: idtop}, 500);
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
div{height:100vh}
#block1{background: #000}
#block1 a{color: #fff}
</style>

<div id="block1">
<a href="#block2">скролл к следующему блоку</a>
</div>
<div id="block2">
<a href="#block1">скролл к предыдущему блоку</a>
</div>
```